# how to make vertical line in html with height in percentage?

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a vertical line inside the div, that div has class flex. I want to put vertical line that should be 50% of that div.
here is my code

```html
<div class="flex flex-row  pl-12">
    <div style="height: 50%;border-left: 1px solid grey " class="flex justify-start items-start"></div>
    <div  class="flex justify-center items-end">
      <hr style="height: 2px;background-color: grey" [ngStyle]="{'width': getWidth(i)}">
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center ml-2 items-center treeAdjust">
      <mat-icon class="TreeIcon" [svgIcon]="item2.icon"></mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center flex-row ml flex-wrap treeAdjust">
      <a [routerLink]="item2.url"
        class="height1 text-cardSubTitle text-cardSubTitle break-words text-brownGrey 
        font-Muli ">
        {{item2.title }}
      </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="flex flex-row  pl-12">
    
    <div class="vl">
    </div>

    <div class="flex justify-center ml-2 items-center treeAdjust">
      <mat-icon class="TreeIcon" [svgicon]="item2.icon"></mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center flex-row ml flex-wrap treeAdjust">
      <a [routerlink]="item2.url" class="height1 text-cardSubTitle text-cardSubTitle break-words text-brownGrey 
        font-Muli ">
        {{item2.title }}
      </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Add css for div with .vl class:

```
.vl {
border-left: 6px solid #b9b9b9;
position: absolute;
left: 2%;
margin-left: -3px;
top: 0;
}
```

Add script:

```
<script>
var myDiv=document.getElementsByClassName("flex");
var divHeight=myDiv[0].clientHeight;
var myVl=document.getElementsByClassName(".vl");
myVl[0].style.height=divHeight/2 + "px";
</script>
```

Comment: But the main div doesn't have a specific height, because it gets the height depending on its content (auto)

Comment: You can get the height of the main div via javascript (clientHeight) and set the height of .vl div using javascript. For example if you name your div's height variable to divHeight, then the height for .vl div will be divHeight/2 (using .style.height)